# Gradle build-attribution unexpected attribution

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I recently deleted and reinstalled my Android Studio IDE and my before working project still finishes building but gives an unexpected exception which is as follows:

*C:/ (...) /.gradle/build-attribution*

The *build-attribution* folder is empty. Also the application on the emulator won't update.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the folder build-attribution and it is fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).